# Python pandas, see exactly the value in the column

Tags: python, string, dataframe, row

I have a dataframe. I want to get describe column for each row. Describe is long string for each row but when i write in python, the definition is shortened. For example:

```
Conceptronic CADSLR1 Router - Denial of Service
```

But python show:

```
Conceptronic CADSLR1 Rout...
```

how can i see this in long form

Comment: print(whatever you want to print)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line of code to the front of your script:

```py
import pandas as pd # Make sure to add as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the est solution is this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [10, 11, 12], 'describe': ['aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaFINISH', 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb', 'cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc']})

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    a = row
    print(a['describe'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the width option

pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)